# Is AES in GCM mode still safe to use? And is there an even better solution to encrypt important data?

Tags: encryption, encryption-symmetric, aes-gcm

I have been searching the Internet for a good solution to securely encrypt my data, but I couldn't really find anything about it.
I would like to have a strong encryption of the data, like in password managers or similar.
I have come across a few algorithms and modes, such as AES-GCM.
Unfortunately, I could not really find out if this is still very secure today.
And even if it is still secure, I wonder if there are some other very secure algorithms?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

AES cipher is still the most current symmetric cipher widely used today.
In encryption there are several modes for symetric block encryption and all (except ECB) are good until used properly.

Very often neglected property of encryption is using authenticated encryption. It means making sure, that the ciphertext was not changed.

AES-GCM has the cipher authentication built-in in the specification. AES-GCM is in top shelf if you need symetric block encryption.

> but I couldn't really find anything about it.

????? There are tons of material, indeed with different level of quality. For more specific answer you should ask more specific question